# Why is there not more to the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

The following will most likely sound like a ramble: I do fully understand how and why the Cauchy-Riemann equations are derived and motivated: In the case of complex valued function, its derivative represents locally a rotation matrix, as per the algebra of complex numbers. But, none of my source material "investigates" what, if anything, happens when we try to calculate the limit of the difference quotient at a point $z_0$ using a curve that moves in both real and imaginary directions. Is the reason that it's enough to consider just the straight line curves along the real and imaginary axis as any other curve in $\mathbb{C}$ is a linear combination of basis vectors along the real and imaginary axis, and hence anything that can be learned from the curve which we use for the limit is learned by investigating the linearly independent directions? Or is there more to this?'

**Postamble:** I am wondering about this question because my CA source material first tells me that one should be able to use (almost) any curve for calculating the complex derivative. Then the material shows the CR equations by taking straight lines along the real and complex axis, and then stop the train of thought regarding the use of different curves in the complex derivative. But without giving any closing words, the CR equations feel like a necessary feature of an analytic function w.r.t. the used curve in the limit, so I am wondering whether there is more to this.

Comment: Perhaps what would be more palatable to you would be the complex derivative approach. A function $f$ is holomorphic on the open set $U$ if $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$ throughout $U$ (so it does not vary with respect to $\bar{z}$). The complex derivative $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$ can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)$. Using the real and imaginary parts of $f$ and the above condition, you get the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: More to the point, you assume that the limit of the difference quotient exists which means that the limit is independent of path. Any other paths will lead to the Cauchy-Riemann equations (there are several equivalent versions of the Cauchy-Riemann equations).

Comment: I believe it can be shown that (differentiability as a two-variable real function) together with (Cauchy–Riemann equations) implies (consistency of derivatives along any curve).

Comment: "its derivative represents locally a rotation matrix" and also a uniform scaling.

Comment: Flippant comment: This is why complex analysis is nicer than real analysis. (I like real analysis, but I think there's something to the idea that it's not as nice...)

Comment: @GregMartin Yes. In fact, you do not even need differentiability and CR equations only in distributional sense imply holomorphicity.